# How to reject a promise i did not create?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, chaining

Fairly new to promises here, and i was wondering..

After taking a look at `bluebird` package for handling promises:

- Creating a Resolver
- Resolve on success / reject on failure
- Returning the created resolver `promise` property

I've been wondering how can i achieve the same effect of rejecting a promise to raise a `catch` using packages that already create the promise, and I'm just using their `.then` chain?

What i mean is, using `reject` on my create resolver will eventually raise a `catch` to the user of this function.

How can i raise a `catch` if i dont have the resolver. chaining the promise as follows :

```
function doSomthing(): Promise<someValue>
    return somePackage.someMethodWithPromise().then((result)=> {
        return someValueToTheNextThen;
    })
}
```

The only way I've seen some packages achieving that is by returning a `{ errors, result }` object so that the next `then` can check if there are any errors and react to it, but I want to raise a `catch` and not check for errors in every single `then` i have..

Hope i made myself clear, please let me know if anything is missing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.then` just returns a Promise as well. You can simply created a rejected promise and return it from there if you determine there’s an error.

```
return somePackage.someMethodWithPromise().then(result => {
  if (result.erroneous()) return Promise.reject('erroneous data');
  return someValueToTheNextThen;
})
```

You can also simply `throw anError;` from the `then` which would also be catched in a `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, looks very PROMISing ;) ill give it a shot tomorrow and accept your answer as soon as i see this work :)

Answer (score 3):

Just as in synchronous code, you can achieve this by throwing an error. This is the idiomatic thing to do when you're using promises and are already inside a `then` chain:

```
function doSomething(): Promise<someValue>
    return somePackage.someMethodWithPromise().then((result)=> {
        if (badResult(result)) { 
            throw new Error('Bad result!'); 
        }

        return someValueToTheNextThen;
    })
}


doSomething()
    .then(result => {
        // this will get skipped if an error was thrown
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error will be caught here if one was thrown
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, ill give it a shot !